# Is there any difference between covariant vectors and one-forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

Just need to have it clarified, are the 2 expressions interchangeable, or is there any difference? I'm trying to learn differential geometry on my own and it is really hard.

Comment: There's no difference between a covariant vector *field* and a $1$-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No difference. Covariant tensor fields of rank $1$ are indeed $1$-forms.

Comment: Perhaps worth elaborating on the difference between "covariant vectors" and "covariant tensor fields." There *is* a potential source of confusion here -- the mathematician's one-form (a field) versus the physicist's (a covariant vector), right? You aren't wrong, of course, since you changed the OP's language from "vectors" to "tensor fields."

Comment: Fair enough, @symplectomorphic. Just keep the physicists' "pseudovector" language out of here :P

Comment: I hate that language too, and I'm not a physicist :) I just think your response misses an opportunity to clarify this issue, which can be so befuddling for beginners.

Comment: We should ask the OP to clarify, I think. What *do* you mean by a covariant vector?

Comment: For a smooth function $f$, $df$ is a covariant vector field; $df_p$ is a covariant vector.

Comment: Oh, duh. I guess I wasn't being sufficiently pedantic. Good thing I've retired :P